azure functions created in one cloud location for example south India should be able to create resource group in location central US
azure functions created in one cloud location for example south India should be able to create resource group in location central US
I want a clear step by step approach if this is possible.
const { ResourceManagementClient } = require("@azure/arm-resources");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    const subscriptionId = process.env["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"];
    const credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const resourceClient = new ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);

    const resourceGroupName = "demoDiffResourceGroup";
    const resourceGroupParameters = {
        location: "centralus"
    };

    context.log(`Creating resource group: ${resourceGroupName} in Central US`);

    try {
        const result = await resourceClient.resourceGroups.createOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, resourceGroupParameters);
        context.res = {
            body: `Resource group created successfully: ${result.name}`
        };
    } catch (err) {
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: `Error creating resource group: ${err.message}`
        };
    }
};


I want it to run in script not through azure portal, a http trigger through postman where I give a location for example central US to azure function situated at south India cloud and my function should be able to create resource group in central US

Do you want to achieve this using Terraform?

I want to code it in VS code

Can you share your code if you tried anything?  Is it C#?

It's in node.js. I've update the code in summary please find it there

Please check my answer below.

I have used below code to create Resource group and Function App in different regions:
Resource group location: Central US
Function App location: South India

Code Snippet:

createResourceGroup function creates a resource group in the specified region.
createFunctionApp function creates an App Service Plan in the defined region and then creates a Function App in the same region.
Orchestrating the creation of both the resource group and the function app in the main function.

const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require('@azure/identity');
const { ResourceManagementClient } = require('@azure/arm-resources');
const { WebSiteManagementClient } = require('@azure/arm-appservice');

const subscriptionId = "<Subscription_id>";
const resourceGroupName = "kprg";
const functionAppName = 'kpfnode';
const resourceGroupLocation = 'CentralUS';
const functionAppLocation = 'southindia';

const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();

const resourceClient = new ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscriptionId);
const webSiteClient = new WebSiteManagementClient(credential, subscriptionId);

// Creation of Resource group in Central US region

async function createResourceGroup() {
    const resourceGroupParams = { location: resourceGroupLocation };
    console.log(`Creating resource group: ${resourceGroupName}`);
    const resourceGroup = await resourceClient.resourceGroups.createOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, resourceGroupParams);
    console.log(`Resource group created: ${resourceGroup.name}`);
}

// Creation of App Service Plan
async function createAppServicePlan() {
  const appServicePlanName = `${functionAppName}Plan`;
  const appServicePlanParams = {
      location: functionAppLocation,
      sku: {
          name: 'Y1',
          tier: 'Dynamic',
          size: 'Y1',
          family: 'Y',
          capacity: 0,
      },
  };
  
  console.log(`Creating App Service Plan: ${appServicePlanName}`);
  const appServicePlan = await webSiteClient.appServicePlans.beginCreateOrUpdateAndWait(resourceGroupName, appServicePlanName, appServicePlanParams);
  console.log(`App Service Plan created: ${appServicePlan.name}`);
}

// Creation of functionapp in South India region

async function createFunctionApp() {
  const siteParams = {
      location: functionAppLocation,
      serverFarmId: `/subscriptions/${subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/${resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/${functionAppName}Plan`,
      siteConfig: {
          appSettings: [
              {
                  name: 'FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION',
                  value: '~3'
              },
              {
                  name: 'WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION',
                  value: '14'
              },
          ],
      },
      kind: 'functionapp',
  };

  console.log(`Creating Function App: ${functionAppName}`);
  const functionApp = await webSiteClient.webApps.beginCreateOrUpdateAndWait(resourceGroupName, functionAppName, siteParams);
  console.log(`Function App created: ${functionApp.name}`);
}

async function main() {
  try {
      await createResourceGroup();
      await createAppServicePlan();
      await createFunctionApp();
  } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error creating resources:', err);
  }
}

main();

Console response:
C:\Users\uname\nodeapp> node app.js
Creating resource group: kprg
Resource group created: kprg
Creating App Service Plan: kpfnodePlan
App Service Plan created: kpfnodePlan
Creating Function App: kpfnode
Function App created: kpfnode

Update:

Use the below updated NodeJs code to achieve your requirement.

const { DefaultAzureCredential } = require("@azure/identity");
const { ResourceManagementClient } = require("@azure/arm-resources");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
  
    const subscriptionId = process.env["AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID"];
    const resourceGroupName = "myResourceGroup";
    const location = "centralus";

    // Authenticate with Azure
    const credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
    const client = new ResourceManagementClient(credential, subscriptionId);

    try {
        // Creation of resource group
        const result = await client.resourceGroups.createOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, {
            location: location
        });
        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: `Resource group created successfully: ${result.id}`
        };
    } catch (error) {
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: `Error creating resource group: ${error.message}`
        };
    }
};


Resource group got created in Central US region:

Function App got created in South India region:


Yes this was a good insights. Thank you for the answer. But I was looking for a way to trigger creation of resource group [to a different location "x"] from a azure function which is at location "y". The function from south india should be able to create a resource group in a different location.

From createFunctionApp()  which creates function app in south India should be able to  trigger createResourceGroup() which in turn creates resource group in central US.

So you want to create a new function in different region after creating the function app. Is my understanding correct?

@Paul, check the updated code in my answer.

A question what is createAppServicePlan() doing ?

It is for creating App Service Plan.

Can you give some more explanation like is it for subscription of the function app created?

In case if you are creating a new function app along with the new resource group, you need an app service plan. The first code snippet can be used in such case. The updated code snippet can be used when you want to create a new resource group while running the function.

@Paul, Is the issue resolved? Let me know if there's anything else I can assist with.

This can be done by

In azure portal, create new Function app example in location central us
In the function app settings turn turn on the system-assigned managed identity.
Assign the managed identity the role of 'Contributor' or a custom role with necessary permissions on the subscription or resource group where you want to create resources.

In my case, my function app is in location south India which should be able to create resource group to a different location
After setting up permissions you can trigger the following code will directly create resource group in a different location from a function which is in other location, use the code snippet:
const { ResourceManagementClient } = require("@azure/arm-resources");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
   const subscriptionId = <subscriptionIdOfFunctionApp;
    const resourceGroupName = <resourceGroupName;
    const location = <location>;

   if (req.body.resourceGroupName && req.body.location) {
       const { resourceGroupName, location } = req.body;
   }
    else{
        context.res = {
            status: 400,
            body: "Please pass a resourceGroupName on the query string or in the request body"
        };
        return;
    }

    try {
        const credentials = new DefaultAzureCredential();
        console.log(credentials)
        const client = new ResourceManagementClient(credentials, subscriptionId);
        console.log(client)
        const result = await client.resourceGroups.createOrUpdate(resourceGroupName, {
            location: location
        });

        context.res = {
            status: 200,
            body: `Resource group '${resourceGroupName}' created in '${location}'`
        };
    } catch (error) {
        context.log.error("Error creating resource group:", error);
        context.res = {
            status: 500,
            body: "Error creating resource group"
        };
    }
};

